# LINQ Join and GroupJoin in same query CS1941

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to join 3 dataset into a List.

PERSONS (physical persons) :

```
var persons = await _context.Persons.ToListAsync();
```

USERS (useraccounts) :

```
var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
```

WORKCONTRACTS :
I'm using a DTO here to lighten the data.

```
var workcontractsList = await _context.Workcontracts
                        .Select(c => new WorkcontractDto()
                        {
                            Id = c.Id,
                            PersonId = c.PersonId,
                            WorkcontractType = c.WorkcontractType,
                            StartDate = c.StartDate,
                            EndDate = c.EndDate
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Each Person may, or not, have a matching User.
Each Person may, or not, have one or more Workcontracts.
The result should be a list of PersonDto each containing a Person, her Username (coming from User) and a list of Workcontracts.

```
 var query = await from p in persons
                    join u in users on p.Id equals u.PersonId
                    join w in workcontractsList on p.Id equals w.PersonId into wlist
                    select (p => new PersonDto()
                    {
                        PersonId = p.Id,
                        Person = p,
                        OrigamiUserName = u.UserName,
                        Workcontracts = wlist.ToList()
                    });
        return query;
```

I get this error :

> CS1941 :  C# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

I tried to remove on of the two joins without success. All the keys used in the joins are of the same type (int) and are enforced at the database level.

Please help.

***SOLUTION FOUND :***

After reading the comments, I  had to admit my approach was wrong. Coming from an Data background, I tend to use "step by step" patterns. I rewrote the query and i works :

```
        var query = await _context.Persons.Select(p => new PersonDto
        {
            PersonId = p.Id,
            Person = p,
            OrigamiUserName = p.OrigamiUser.UserName,
            Workcontracts = p.Workcontracts.Select(c => new WorkcontractDto 
                { 
                    Id = c.Id,
                    PersonId = c.PersonId,
                    WorkcontractType = c.WorkcontractType,
                    StartDate = c.StartDate,
                    EndDate = c.EndDate
                }).ToList()
        }).ToArrayAsync();
            
        return query;
```

I guess I could still optimize it more, but, so far, it works as intended.

Thanks for the multiple heads up !

Comment: Are the types of `p.Id`, `u.PersonId`, `w.PersonId` all the same? For example are they all Int32, Int64, String or is one different.?

Comment: They're all Int32.I tried "cheating" by converting them to string but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why you have add .ToListAsync() for each recordset? Maybe it is better to do that on SQL Server?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `await` on `query` when it is only doing LINQ to Objects. @SvyatoslavDanyliv is correct, you shouldn't `await` / `ToListAsync()` the `query` components, just do it on `query`.

Comment: Which `join` did you try to remove? Since you instantiated into LINQ to Objects (incorrectly), are some of your keys `int?` (nullable) instead of all `int`?

Comment: @NetMage : Thanks for the heads up on `await` / `async`.  As for the keys, none of them are explicitly nullable.I tries to remove both join (with `users` and with `workcontracts`) and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I had to admit my approach was wrong. Coming from an Data background, I tend to use "step by step" patterns. I rewrote the query and i works :

```
    var query = await _context.Persons.Select(p => new PersonDto
    {
        PersonId = p.Id,
        Person = p,
        OrigamiUserName = p.OrigamiUser.UserName,
        Workcontracts = p.Workcontracts.Select(c => new WorkcontractDto 
            { 
                Id = c.Id,
                PersonId = c.PersonId,
                WorkcontractType = c.WorkcontractType,
                StartDate = c.StartDate,
                EndDate = c.EndDate
            }).ToList()
    }).ToArrayAsync();
        
    return query;
```

I guess I could still optimize it more, but, so far, it works as intended.

Thanks for the multiple heads up !